# MapReduce: How can a streaming mapper know which file data comes from?

Tags: java, python, input, mapreduce, streaming

I am learning MapReduce. I'm trying as a test to set up a 'join' algorithm that takes in data from two files (which contain the two data sets to join).

For this to work, the mapper needs to know which file each line is from; this way, it can tag it appropriately, so that the reducer doesn't (for instance) join elements from one data set to other elements from the same set.

To complicate the matter, I am using Hadoop Streaming, and the mapper and reducer are written in Python; I understand Java, but the documentation for the Hadoop InputFormat and RecordReader classes are gloriously vague and I don't understand how I'd make a Streaming-compatible split so that some sort of file identifier could be bundled in along with the data.

Anyone who can explain how to set up this input processing in a way that my Python programs can understand?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out the answer, by the way— in Python, it's:

```
import os
context = os.environ["map_input_file"]
```

And 'context' then has the input file name.